# Is there up to date OSM SLD file for GeoServer?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, sld

I've tried looking for some but only found old from 2009 which are apparently out of date.
Any help will be welcome.

This is the sld I was looking at:

https://github.com/mitchelljj/openstreetmap-sld

Comment: Could you post the link of SLD file you found? That way, we won't be giving you answers you already know.

Comment: Done mate. I hope there is up to date one .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't been able to find up to date SLD files either but you can use [mapnik2geotools](https://github.com/dwins/mapnik2geotools) to convert Mapnik styles to SLD. You can get the OSM.org Mapnik style files at the [svn](http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applications/rendering/mapnik) repository.

It's not quite what you asked for you but should have the SLD file you want in the end. Found that suggestion at the [OpenStreetMap Q&A site](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/7521/geoserver-style-files).

Comment: Nobody did it yet and uploaded somewhere ?

Comment: I don't know. I can't find a recent one either.

Comment: If I'll do such a thing , will share with the community

Comment: I'm running windows machine. Is there installation for mapnik2geotools for win ?

Comment: Sorry. None that I know of. Maybe use a virtual machine?

Comment: It's kinda overkill to setup VM Linux just for one time use of tool

Comment: Will mapnik2geotools run with cygwin?